# How can i replace duplicate integers in an ArrayList with the missing integers

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, integer

I want to replace duplicate integers in an ArrayList of size n with missing integers. For Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myNumbers.add(1);
    myNumbers.add(2);
    myNumbers.add(1);
    myNumbers.add(3);
    myNumbers.add(1);
   
  }
}
```

The arraylist has 5 elements so it should contain the numbers 1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 5 (not in a specific order).
(if the size was 99, there should be numbers from 1 to 99 without duplicates).

it should go from [1,2,1,3,1] to [1,2,4,3,5] or [1,2,5,3,4]. It has to work for any size and there can be multiple duplicates.

For now i can only get rid of the duplicates using a set but i have no idea of to replace them with the missing elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First find out the missing values
2. Iterate over your list and check if the current value is a duplicate. If true replace with one of the missing values

Assuming you are using java 8 or higher something like below could be a starting point:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> myNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        myNumbers.add(1);
        myNumbers.add(2);
        myNumbers.add(1);
        myNumbers.add(3);
        myNumbers.add(1);
        System.out.println("original: " + myNumbers);
        List<Integer> missing = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,myNumbers.size())
                .filter(i -> !myNumbers.contains(i))
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("missing: " + missing);

        Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>();
        Iterator<Integer> misIterator = missing.iterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < myNumbers.size(); i++){
            if(!unique.add(myNumbers.get(i))){
                myNumbers.set(i, misIterator.next());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("modified" + myNumbers);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of the question/problem statement:

- Your input is a list of possibly duplicated numbers 1 - n where n is never larger than the size of the list.
- The first instance (non-duplicate) of a number while iterating the list should be left at its current index.
- Each subsequent duplicate of a number found while iterating the list should be replaced with a number from the "missing set".
- The "missing set" contains all numbers 1 - n where n is the size of the list with the existing set (from the input list) removed.
- The end result list should contain all numbers 1 - `listSize` with no duplicates and the first instance of any numbers (while iterating from the start of the list) left at the same index as the input list.

If the statements above sound correct, here's one way of doing it (although there is probably a more optimized way of doing it):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ReplaceDuplicateIntegersRunner {
    private static ArrayList<Integer> sampleIntegerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addRandomIntegersToList(3,7);
        System.out.println("List Before: " + sampleIntegerList);
        replaceDuplicatesWithContinuedCount();
        System.out.println("List After: " + sampleIntegerList);

    }

    public static void addRandomIntegersToList(Integer maxValue, Integer numOfIntegers) {
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        for (int num = 0; num < numOfIntegers; num++) {
            sampleIntegerList.add(1 + randomGen.nextInt(maxValue));
        }
    }

    public static void replaceDuplicatesWithContinuedCount() {
        // generate a set of integers 1 - length of sampleIntegerList
        Set<Integer> integerSetToAdd = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, sampleIntegerList.size())
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        // remove the integers which already exist in the target sample list
        integerSetToAdd.removeAll(new HashSet<>(sampleIntegerList));
        ArrayList<Integer> integersToReplaceDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        integersToReplaceDuplicates.addAll(integerSetToAdd);
        int indexOfIntegersToAdd = 0;
        HashSet<Integer> duplicatesInList = new HashSet<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < sampleIntegerList.size(); index++) {
            // if our duplicate set doesn't already have this number, we don't have a duplicate, add it to the set
            // and continue on
            Integer integerAtIndex = sampleIntegerList.get(index);
            if (duplicatesInList.contains(integerAtIndex) == false) {
                duplicatesInList.add(integerAtIndex);
            } else {
                // otherwise we've found a duplicate and need to replace it with the next one to replace
                sampleIntegerList.set(index, integersToReplaceDuplicates.get(indexOfIntegersToAdd));
                indexOfIntegersToAdd++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some sample outputs with the passed in params from above:

> List Before: [3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1]
> List After: [3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7]

> List Before: [2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
> List After: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a sequence of numbers *not in a specific order*, you can create it and replace old one:

```java
List<Integer> list = IntStream
        // from 1 to 5 inclusive
        .rangeClosed(1, 5)
        // Stream<Integer>
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

// random order
Collections.shuffle(list);

System.out.println(list); // [2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
```